# Как инициализировать список значениями разного класса?

Tags: c++, c, list

По заданию необходимо создать двух связный список. Для заполнения поля данных в узле, предварительно создана иерархия классов.Shape(базовый)и Rect,Circle(производные от Shape). Создана функция произвольно генерирующая объекты Rect и Circle. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в конструкторе узла проинициализировать поле data этими объектами?

Shape.h

```
class Shape
{
public:

    enum Color { Red, Black, Green, Blue };

protected:

    Color color;

public:

    Shape(int x = 0);// конструктор с одним параметром
    Shape(const Shape& other);// конструктор крпирования
    
    virtual~Shape();

    void Set_Color(int x); // присваим значение 
    int Get_Color();       // принимаем значение 

    void printMyShape();   // распичатываем

    bool operator == (const Shape& other);
    bool operator != (const Shape& other);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Shape& an);
         
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Shape& an);
```

Shape.cpp

```
Shape::Shape(int x)
{
    this->color = static_cast<Color>(x);
}

Shape::Shape(const Shape& other)
{
    color = other.color;
}

Shape::~Shape()
{
    std::cout << "Now I am in Shape's destructor!" << std::endl;
}

void Shape::Set_Color(int x)
{
    this->color = static_cast<Color>(x);
}

int Shape::Get_Color()
{
    return this->color;
}

void Shape::printMyShape()
{
    std::cout << this->color << std::endl;
}

bool Shape::operator==(const Shape& other)
{
    return this->color == other.color;
}

bool Shape::operator!=(const Shape& other)
{
    return !(this->color == other.color);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Shape& an)
{
    os << an.color;
    return os;
```

Rect.h

```
class Rect :public Shape
{
    int m_left, m_right, m_top, m_bottom;

public:
    Rect();
    Rect(int color, int l, int r, int t, int b); // создали конструктор с параметрами
    Rect(const Rect& nov); // конструктор копирования
    //~Rect();
    //virtual~Rect();

    //--------------------------------методы------------------------------------------------------


    void Norm();                                     // проверка введенных данных
    void Print();                                    // печать
    void SetAll(int a, int b, int c, int d);         // присваиваем значения переменным класса

    int GetRect_left() const;
    int GetRect_right() const;
    int GetRect_top() const;
    int GetRect_bottom() const;
    int GetAll(int& left, int& right, int& top, int& bottom);

    int SquareRect();//вычисляем площадь прямоугольника

    bool operator ==(const Rect& other);
    bool operator !=(const Rect& other);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Rect& other);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Rect& other);
```

Rect.cpp

```
Rect::Rect() :Shape(color)
{
    m_left = 0;
    m_right = 0;
    m_top = 0;
    m_bottom = 0;
}


Rect::Rect(int color, int l, int r, int t, int b):Shape(color)
{
    m_left = l;
    m_right = r;
    m_top = t;
    m_bottom =b;
}

Rect::Rect(const Rect& nov):Shape(color)
{
    m_left = nov.m_left;
    m_right = nov.m_right;
    m_top = nov.m_top;
    m_bottom = nov.m_bottom;
}

//Rect::~Rect()
//{
//}

void Rect::Norm()
{
    if (m_left > m_right)
    {
        std::swap(m_left, m_right); // меняем местами значения переменных
    }

    if (m_top > m_bottom)
    {
        std::swap(m_top, m_bottom);
    }
}

void Rect::Print()
{
    std::cout << color << " " << m_left << " " << m_right << " " << m_top << " " << m_bottom << std::endl;
}

void Rect::SetAll(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    this->m_left = a;
    this->m_right = b;
    this->m_top = c;
    this->m_bottom = d;
}

int Rect::GetRect_left() const
{
    return this->m_left;
}

int Rect::GetRect_right() const
{
    return this->m_right;
}

int Rect::GetRect_top() const
{
    return this->m_top;
}

int Rect::GetRect_bottom() const
{
    return this->m_bottom;
}

int Rect::GetAll(int& left, int& right, int& top, int& bottom)
{
    std::pair <int, int> PAIR1;
    PAIR1.first = m_left;
    PAIR1.second = m_right;

    std::pair <int, int> PAIR2;
    PAIR2.first = m_top;
    PAIR2.second = m_bottom;

    return 0;
}

int Rect::SquareRect()
{
    int SquareR = (m_right - m_left ) * (m_bottom- m_top);

    return SquareR;
}

bool Rect::operator==(const Rect& other)
{
    return this->m_left == other.m_left  &&  this->m_top == other.m_top;
}

bool Rect::operator!=(const Rect& other)
{
    return !(this->m_left == other.m_left && this->m_top == other.m_top);
}



std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Rect& other)
{
    os << other.GetRect_left() << " " << other.GetRect_right() << " " << other.GetRect_top() << " " << other.GetRect_bottom();

    return os;
}
```

Circle.h

```
class Circle :public Shape
{
    int x, y, radius;

public:
    Circle();// конструктор без параметров

    Circle(int color, int x, int y, int r); //конструктор с парометрами

    Circle(const Rect& x);

    Circle(const Circle& other); //конструктор копирования

    //~Circle();
    //virtual~Circle();

    void SetCircle(int x, int y, int r, int color);
    int GetLeft();
    int GetTop();
    int GetRadius();
    void PrintCircle();

    int SquareCircle();//вычисляем площадь прямоугольника

    bool operator == (const Circle& other);
    bool operator != (const Circle& other);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Circle& other);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Circle& other);
```

Circle.cpp

```
Circle::Circle():Shape(color)
{
    this->x = 0;
    this->y = 0;
    this->radius = 0;
}

Circle::Circle(int color, int x, int y, int r) :Shape(color)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->radius = r;
}

Circle::Circle(const Rect& x) :Shape(color)
{
    this->x = x.GetRect_left();
    this->y = x.GetRect_top();
    this->radius = x.GetRect_right();
}

Circle::Circle(const Circle& other) :Shape(color)
{
    this->x = other.x;
    this->y = other.y;
    this->radius = other.radius;
}

//Circle::~Circle()
//{
//  std::cout << "Now I am in Shape's destructor!" << std::endl;
//}

void Circle::SetCircle(int x, int y, int r, int color)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->radius = radius;
    this->color = static_cast<Color>(color);
}

int Circle::GetLeft()
{
    return this->x;
}

int Circle::GetTop()
{
    return this->y;
}

int Circle::GetRadius()
{
    return this->radius;
}

void Circle::PrintCircle()
{
    std::cout << this->color << " " << this->x << " " << this->y << " " << this->radius << std::endl;
}

int Circle::SquareCircle()
{
    int SquareC = 3.14 * (radius * radius);

    return 0;
}

bool Circle::operator==(const Circle& other)
{
    return this->x== other.x && this->y== other.y;
}

bool Circle::operator!=(const Circle& other)
{
    return !(this->x == other.x && this->y == other.y);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Circle& other)
{
    os << other.x << " " << other.y << other.radius;

    return os;
}
```

Node.h

```
class Node
    {
        Node* pPrev;
        Node* pNext;
        Shape* m_data;
        Shape* Make();

     public:
        Node(Node* p, const Shape*);

        ~Node();
    };
```

Node.cpp

```
Shape* List::Node::Node::Make()
{
    switch (rand()%2)
    {
    case 0:
    return new Rect;
    case 1:
    return new Circle;
    }
}

List::Node::Node(Node* p, const Shape* sh) :m_data(*sh)
{
    this->pPrev = p;
    this->pNext = p->pNext;
    p->pNext = this;
    pNext->pPrev = this;
}
```

Comment: Ваш конструктор Node уже принимает указатель на Shape, разыменовывать не нужно. Правда зачем функция Make внутри Node -  я не знаю, она лишняя

Comment: Я не уверен, что функцию Make нужно вставлять в конструкторе. Но по логике тип данных узла должен  определятся в конструкторе. А Вы как бы сделали?

Comment: я бы просто убрал константость  и готово `List::Node::Node(Node* p, Shape* sh) :m_data(sh)`. Правда в коде есть куча очень странных кусков кода - `Rect::Rect() :Shape(color)` - здесь идет обращение к неинициализированной переменной класса. Так нельзя. Там либо константа должна быть, либо конструктор Rect должен принимать параметр для цвета.

Comment: Спасибо большое!